# Using for loop to get table data

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a for loop to get a table for 6 rows. How can i use for loop to create a table to show the data that i want to show?
I need to display a table showing the data on the right side of the table but i can't get it.

This is my code for html:

```
<div id="yr" class="year"></div>
```

This is my code for js:

```
    function repayment() {
        var x = document.getElementById("yr");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }

        var test, tr;

        test = '<table border="1px"><thead><tr><th> Year</th ></tr> <tr><th>' 
             + 'Month</th ></tr>  <tr><th>Repayment</th ></tr> <tr><th>Interest</th ></tr>' 
             + '<tr>' 
             + '<th>Loan Paid</th ></tr> <tr><th>Loan Balance</th ></tr></thead><tbody>';
        tr = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            tr += '<tr>' + '<tr>';
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                tr += '<td>' + 12;
            }
        }
        tr += '</tr>';
        test += tr;
        return document.getElementById('yr').innerHTML = test;
    }
    repayment();
```

My results when i click the button :

[image]

Comment: you close the TR before adding your TDs...and don't close the TDs either

Comment: And to add to what @Ctznkane525 said, you put each of your headings in their own row, which is why they display each on their own row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
            test = '<table border="1px"><thead><tr><th> Year</th ></tr> <tr><th>' 
                 + 'Month</th ></tr>  <tr><th>Repayment</th ></tr> <tr><th>Interest</th ></tr>' 
                 + '<tr>' 
                 + '<th>Loan Paid</th ></tr> <tr><th>Loan Balance</th ></tr></thead><tbody>';
```

use

```
            test = '<table border="1px">'
                   + '<thead>'
                     + '<tr>'
                       + '<th>Year</th>'
                       + '<th>Month</th>
                       + '<th>Repayment</th>'
                       + '<th>Interest</th>'
                       + '<th>Loan Paid</th>'
                       + '<th>Loan Balance</th>'
                     + '</tr>'
                   + '</thead>'
                   + '<tbody>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line `'<table border="1px"><thead><tr><th> Year</th ></tr> <tr><th>Month</th ></tr>  <tr><th>Repayment</th ></tr> <tr><th>Interest</th ></tr><tr> 
 + '<th>Loan Paid</th ></tr> <tr><th>Loan Balance</th ></tr></thead><tbody>'`.

With every `td` you are closing the row using `</tr>`/ So it will create new rows.

An alternative & clean solution is to use template literals and create rows in a separate function

```js
function repayment() {
  var x = document.getElementById("yr");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    //x.style.display = "none";
  }

  var test, tr;

  test =
    `<table border="1px">
         <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Repayment</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th> Loan Paid </th>
            <th> Loan Balance </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>${createRows()}</tbody>
    </table>`;
  document.getElementById("yr").innerHTML = test;
}
repayment();

function createRows() {
  let tr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tr += '<tr>' + '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      tr += '<td>' + 12;
    }
  }
  return tr;

}
```

```html
<div id="yr" class="year"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  repayment();
});



function repayment() {
        var x = document.getElementById("yr");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }

        var test, tr;

        test = '<table border="1px"> <thead> <tr> <th>Year</th> <th>Month</th> <th>Repayment</th> <th>Interest</th> <th>Loan Paid</th> <th>Loan Balance</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody>';
        tr = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            tr += '<tr>' + '<tr>';
            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                tr += '<td>' + 12;
            }
        }
        tr += '</tr>';
        test += tr;
        return document.getElementById('yr').innerHTML = test;
    }
    repayment();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>APTARA</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="yr" class="year"></div>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```